# What is the domain of definition of time $t$ in physics?

Tags: classical-mechanics, time, definition, boundary-conditions, models

Time $t$ is often used as variable of physical quantity, like $E (r, t)$.

In most EM, acoustic and other wave tutorials, equations (maxwell’s equations, acoustic equations, …) and wave function (EM wave $\cos (\omega t-kz)$ and $\exp(i\omega t)$, harmonic motion $\cos(\omega t)$, pulse wave $f(t)$, etc) have variable $t$, but the range of $t$ is usually not shown explicitly.

For the cases initial conditions are given, or the diagrams of harmonic motion that set $t \geq 0$, the time $t$ might not be allowed to be negative.

However, when performing fourier transform, $t$ is usually set to be from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$.

Then what is the domain of definition of time $t$ in physics (expecially when no explicit definition is given, which is a common case)?
Is the domain of $t$ from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$ or just nonnegative number?

(Please discuss in SI units, I am not sure whether different unit systems will have different conclusions)

Answer (score 2):

t runs between $- \infty$ and $ \infty$. When necessary, especially with integral transforms, one uses Heavyside's function to limit the domain.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. For the cases initial conditions are given, or the diagrams of harmonic motion that set t>=0 (in most of the harmonic diagrams, t<0 will not be shown), how to understand the range of the time t? For example, every tutorial (including EM theory), the most simple example of wave, cos(wt+α) with initial phase α, will be given to illustrate the basic concept of wave. The tutorial always say α is the phase when t=0. This make me suspect that, t is not allowed to be negative, because the word 'initial' phase is used.

Comment: In Fourier transforms, t varies between the $-\infty$ and $\infty$. The real signal can have any  domain.  As a matter of fact, the smaller the domain of f(t) the larger the ones of its Fourier transform. $cos(\omega t)$is defined on R, is not square summable but an infinite superposition of it with proper coefficients can be used to represent time bounded, square summable functions.

Comment: Then what's your opinion about the comment I give? "For the cases initial conditions are given, or the diagrams of harmonic motion that set t>=0 (in most of the harmonic diagrams, t<0 will not be shown), how to understand the range of the time t? For example, every tutorial (including EM theory), the most simple example of wave, cos(wt+α) with initial phase α, will be given to illustrate the basic concept of wave. The tutorial always say α is the phase when t=0. This make me suspect that, t is not allowed to be negative, because the word 'initial' phase is used."

Comment: @ChuaJiaCai initial time simply means time for which we have data. In case of a sin wave, it could have existed before, but we measured its phase at the time 0. Anyway, physicists tend to let domains be implicit. It is obvious that the sine wave did not existed for all times, since not even our universe existed for all possible values of t and the sine wave most probably gets absorbed (or something) in the future. But physics models are usually idealized and extended to infinites for simplicity.

Comment: @Umaxo Let me try to understand your words. 1) For the cases where range of t is not shown, in equations or functions, t should be from -∞ to ∞; 2) For the cases initial conditions are given, or the diagrams of harmonic motion that set t>=0, t is allowed to be negative (but not shown in diagrams). For example, cos(wt+α)，α is the initial phase determined by initial condition, and this function has the value of cos(w*(-1 s)+α) at t = -1 s; for harmonic motion diagram, the function value of t<0 is not 0 and should be repeated as cos curves (but not shown). Am I right?

Comment: @ChuaJiaCai I do not think there are any such general rules. You just need to understand it from the context. Usually, the model is extended for all values of t for which it makes sense, but I cannot say to you the function value of t<0 in an unknown diagram. Maybe the sine wave was actually generated in t=0? Physics is rarely as rigorous as math - validity of the model and its domains are usually left implicit in the context of your problem. Mathematically, the harmonic motion makes sense for all t, but when applying this model in actual situations, this might not be the case.

Comment: @ChuaJiaCai When physicists study harmonic motion without any context, they get sine solution for all t. This solution depends on some constants that can be determined by measurement at some value of t, conveniently chosen to be t=0 (since physics is time translation invariant). Physicists call it initial condition, but it does not mean that the harmonic motion started at t=0. So physicists studying harmonic motion without any context give you sine solution for all t, and it is up to you to decide in which domain is this solution valid within your problem and restrict it appropriately.

Comment: @Umaxo I understand your words. If in experiments, it's hard to say. But for theories, it is ok to think t is from -∞ to ∞. For example, when analyzing EM waves calculated from maxwell's equations, or acoustic waves  calculated from acoustic equations, the point 2) in my former comment is correct ('For the cases initial conditions are given, or the diagrams of harmonic motion that set t>=0, t is allowed to be negative (but not shown in diagrams). For example, ... as cos curves (but not shown). ').  Right?

Answer (score 2):

In physics there is no consensus on the "domain" of time. There really can be no consensus since all theories must be valid for any choice of coordinates (including choice of a parameter we call time).

Writing this a little mathematically all **physics** must be invariant to the translation of time
$$
t \rightarrow t + a,
$$
where (for example!) $a \in \mathbb{R}$.
Also we usually require that the **physics** be invariant to scaling
$$
t \rightarrow \lambda t.
$$
Notice the emphasis on **physics**, this is because the math itself can be different and even have some local problems which usually need further consideration to extract the physics of it all.

To answer your question more directly a less correctly: t is always allowed to be negative, but sometimes this might result in mathematical consequences which should be treated with care.

Note that there are examples where we can take time to be $t \in \mathbb{C}$ so we should really treat is just as an parameter.

Comment: Let's only discuss about physics. You said 't is always allowed to be negative'. For the cases initial conditions are given, or the diagrams of harmonic motion that set t>=0 (in most of the harmonic diagrams, t<0 will not be shown), how to understand the range of the time t? For example, every tutorial (including EM theory), the most simple example of wave, cos(wt+α) with initial phase α, will be given to illustrate the basic concept of wave. The tutorial always say α is the phase when t=0. This make me suspect that, t is not allowed to be negative, because the word 'initial' phase is used.

Comment: Yet this is only a matter of convention. The term initial is used, because in your book you are used to setting the initial time to $t_0$ yet this has no physical consequence.
Perhaps it's better for me to provide a example.
Consider a wave described by the function $\cos(\omega t + \alpha)$, now let's consider the transformation $t* = t - 2 \pi$ so we have a wave described by $cos(\omega t* + \alpha)$. Now you would probably say that the initial phase is at $t* = 0$, yet this corresponds to $t = - 2 \pi$. Since the output of the function is the same the physics remains the same.

Comment: Let me try to understand your words. 1) For the cases where range of t is not shown, in equations or functions, t should be from -∞ to ∞; 2) For the cases initial conditions are given, or the diagrams of harmonic motion that set t>=0, t is allowed to be negative (but not shown in diagrams). For example, cos(wt+α)，α is the initial phase determined by initial condition, and this function has the value of cos(w*(-1 s)+α) at t = -1 s; for harmonic motion diagram, the function value of t<0 is not 0 and should be repeated as cos curves (but not shown). Am I right?

Comment: Yes I would say what you are saying is ok. But, you should aways consider that these are only the parameters we choose. We can choose any arbritary systems coordinate system (including the time coordinate) and the physics ALWAYS stays the same. For further reference I would advise to read the introduction in any good special relativity book.

Answer (score 1):

Physics is not mathematics. We choose our concept of time according to the problem we're addressing. The SI definition of the second changes as we learn to build better clocks.

Mathematically, the domain is chosen to match the problem we're solving. In an "initial value" problem, time starts at the boundary and continues for as long as we choose. If we're analyzing the dynamics of a system that has existed for a long time and will continue to exist for a long time, we might choose a domain of $-\infty$ to $\infty$ for convenience. Depending on the system, a "long time" might only be a nanosecond. Choice of the domain does not imply a commitment to the idea that real physical time matches the domain.

Comment: But the range of t is not shown in most cases. For example, in EM theory, the function of wave is given (like E*exp(iwt)), how do I know whether t is from −∞? This is ambiguous for me.

Comment: @ChuaJiaCai What physical system are you analyzing? What's the experiment? That determines the domain you choose.

Comment: Let's discuss about theory (I know there is start point for experiment, and time before start point is meaningless). For example, I begin to learn EM theory, read the part of plane wave, then a function is given (E*exp(i(wt-kz))). Then, how do I know the range of t?

Comment: @ChuaJiaCai Theory is meaningless without grounding in reality. The range of t depends on the real-world system you're attempting to model. If you're not attempting to model a real-world system, you're not doing physics.